# ggplot shows all Y-axis values instead of calibrating

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I plotted a ggplot for a couple of variables using side-by side bars, but it seems the y-axis is shown without any calibration-displays every number(in %)
[image: police_kills]

The topic of the plot is to show the share of white,hispanic and black people (%) out of the whole population in each state in the US. as you can see, the Y axis that is supposed to represent the percent, looks like all the values had been pushed inside it instead of a calibration from 0 to 100

The dataset I am using is presented at [github_fivethirtyeight_police-killings](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/police-killings) (I am sorry but I couldn't find a way to organize the five columns I am taking from the dataframe: state, ethnicity, and the three shares you are seeing on the right(in %)

the R code is presented:
`x<-read.csv("C:/Users/USER/data/police-killings/police_killings.csv",header=TRUE, sep = "," ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
state<-x[,10]
ethnicity<-x[,4]
state_and_shares<-x[,c(10,23:25)]`

`df2<-melt(state_and_shares, id.vars = 'state')
head(df2)`

`ggplot(df2,aes(x=state,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = 'dodge')+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`

can someone please tell me how can I factor the Y values to look more normal and to not display all the values?

Comment: This is could be because your `value` column is not numerical. try running `df2$value <- as.numeric(df2$value)` before running the ggplot. Also this would be much easier to answer if you shared a subset of you actual data using `dput`.

Comment: since melt coerces values and variables into factors, the plot presents y values which are very big(in the thousands). I tried coercing it to char before numeric but melt still somehow mixed the values so I get things like: in a certain country there is 99% hispanic, 95% white, 90% black, which does not add up to 100%

Answer (score 1):

You need ggplot to see the y values as numbers and not strings, eg. with as.numeric():

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=state,y=as.numeric(value),fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = 'dodge')+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I was turning to everyone I could today to help me with this, and I figured the problem, sorry for the delay. The thing is, the dataset was based partly on surveys that were taken at census areas and the share_white etc were based on that, meaning that if there were 10 killings in one state but in different census blocks, the share_white etc would show the population of these particular groups relative to every census block in that state, making it obvious why adding up the share_ in one country goes way above the 100%. 
Thanks for your answer! By the way, as.numeric(as.string(df)) worked

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding!